# How to use letters based on pseudo-random numbers to encode a given string, using lists, string methods, dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, encoding

Alphabet table:

```
Letter - `a, b, c, d, ... z`.  
Number - `0, 1, 2, 3, ... 25`.
```

Encoding Table:

```
Number - `0, 1, 2, 3, ...25`.  
Code (from random seed 202090) - `23, 15, 1, 22, ...` (same length as letters above).
```

**Using Table 1 and Table 2, any letter can be encoded as follows:**

1. Look up the letter's number in Table 1 (e.g. 'm' corresponds to number 12).
2. Lookup the code in Table 2 (e.g. number 12 corresponds to code 10).
3. Lookup the code back in Table 1 to get the coded letter (e.g. code 10 corresponds to
   letter 'k').
4. Covert the coded letter to upper case (e.g. coded letter 'k' is converted to 'K').

It is the second part of actually encoding message/file content I am struggling with.

Not allowed to import modules other than a standard random module.

Have to use string methods, lists, and dictionaries.
[image: 1]

```py
import random

def main():
    user = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    random.seed(user)
    message = input('Enter message: ') 
    create_code_list(user)
    encode(user,message)

def create_code_list(user):
    letter = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    code_list = (random.sample(range(0,26),len(letter)))
    print (code_list)
    return code_list

def encode(code_list,message):
    letter = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    letter_list = list(letter)
    code_list = create_code_list(letter_list)
    string_list = list(string)
    c = {}
    for i in range(len(letter_list)):
        c[string_list[i]] = letter[i]
    
main()
```

Comment: You're overwriting some arguments, ignoring and discarding other variables, and you are trying to transform the built-in `string` type into a list. I suggest looking at each and every identifier used in that code and writing down where exactly it comes from and what it means _at that point in the program_.

Comment: Ok I edited the image in. If I made any mistake then correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you want to encode and decode the given word? See the repo I have published in git-hub: [Simple-Cryptography](https://github.com/Parvat-web-dev/Simple-Cryptography).The code might be long. See this code:

```py
#An inbuilt module which contains all the printables
import string

letters = [] #A list where all the printable letters will be added.
numbers = [] #A list which contains the equal number of elements with letters


for letter in string.printable:
    letters.append(letter)  #Append the letter to the list named letters

for number in range(0, len(letters)):
    numbers.append(number)  #Append the number in the list named numbers


#Create a dict that contains all the keys as letters and the values as numbers.
encode_dict = dict(zip(letters, numbers))

#Create a dict that contains all the keys as numbers and the values as letters.
decode_dict = dict(zip(numbers, letters))

#A function that encodes the given key:
def encode():

    #Get the input from user:
    text_to_encode = str(input('The Text To Encode: '))

    #A string which will contain all the decoded numbers:
    encoded_text = ''

    #Append the values for the keys as the letter in the inputted text:
    for letter in text_to_encode:
        encoded_text = encoded_text + str(encode_dict[letter]) + " "   #Include The " "(white space) to make it decodable! !important

    #Print the encoded text
    print(encoded_text)

def decode():

    #Get the input from user:
    text_to_decode = str(input('The Text To Decode: '))

    #a string that contains all the decoded letter:
    decoded_text = ''

    #Append the values for the keys as the letter in the inputted text:
    for letter in text_to_decode.split(): #Remove the white_space to identify the letter .split() !important
        
        decoded_text = decoded_text + str(decode_dict[int(letter)]) #Convert the letter to 'int' because the keys are int !important

    print(decoded_text)

#The end of the code!
```

When I Run This:

```py
>>> encode()
The Text To Encode: stackoverflow
28 29 10 12 20 24 31 14 27 15 21 24 32 
>>> decode()
The Text To Decode: 28 29 10 12 20 24 31 14 27 15 21 24 32 
stackoverflow
>>>
```

In this you can input any letter or number that is on your keyboard!

Comment: Hope This Helps You.

Comment: But if you use Random, every time you run your program, the number will change. So I recommend you not to use random. Else when you encode some text and try decoding it by restarting the terminal you will not encode it.

Comment: Hi Parvat.R, thanks. this is a past assignment question...Instructions were to use user stated seed value. Only random module is allowed to be used, in addition to list, string methods, and dictionary.

Comment: Ok, no problem, you can remove the first for loop and the import string statement. In the list of letters just put the characters as string and everything will work out